# php -v command does not work

Tags: php, debian

I have just installed the php5 package on my Debian system using the standard apt-get. The code:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

works and other php pages work.

But the commands php -v and php -m do not work. It gives an error "-bash: php: command not found".

php5-cli is installed. My path is /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games. I looked into usr/bin and there is no php or php5 file. Not sure where else those can be located?

I ran:

```
whereis php5
php5: /etc/php5 /usr/lib/php5 /usr/lib64/php5 /usr/share/php5
```

Dont think any of those are the correct file?

Comment: Have you got PHP CLI installed?

Comment: Run `which php` and see if PHP is in your path.

Answer (score 9):

Make sure that the PHP CLI package is installed. `sudo apt-get install php5-cli`.

Also, the PHP binary needs to be added to your path. If you run `which php` and get no output, then it is certain that it is not in your path.

Answer (score 3):

The php command is probably not in your path. You can view your path with `echo $PATH`. If the directory where the php binary is installed is not in your path, you can set it with `export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/php`.

Comment: php5-cli is installed. My path is /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games. I looked into usr/bin and there is no php or php5 file. Not sure where else those can be located?

Comment: I ran: whereis php5
php5: /etc/php5 /usr/lib/php5 /usr/lib64/php5 /usr/share/php5

Comment: I'd re-install php5-cli, because the binary (the command line interface) is missing.

Comment: What is the command to re-install? sudo apt-get install --reinstall packagename?

Comment: @GodAtum You can see a list of files installed by a package with `dpkg -L <packagename>`